# Can SDL2 work with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sdl

I am following this [tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php) but apparently this error shows up

> LNK1104 cannot open file 'SDL2.lib'

Now I traced back my steps but apparently all the files & directories are in the place that the tutorial said. **I know there are people** who had the same problem as mine but their problem got solved in their answers but they have different Visual studio versions from mine, which is 2015. I also tried doing the some of the answers in the forums I've visited. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you. Do not post links to your problem, the SO search feature can't search the target of links and when your link dies your question will no longer make sense. Also, if you tried doing something you have to tell us what you did, we weren't standing behind you watching while you did it.

Comment: You know I still hope you actually looked into the link and test it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a way to get around this. It is true that Visual Studio 2015 is having problems with the current SDL version. However this [link](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/setting-up-sdl2-with-visual-studio-2015/) would help solve the problems to all you out there having trouble with this. :)